# Defining datalog query components outside of (datomic.api/q '[])

Tags: clojure, datomic, datalog

I am working with clojure's datomic.api. I wish to refactor a somewhat complex datalog query such as this:

```
(datomic.api/q '[:find [?value ...] :in $ ?uid ?component :where
                [...some clause...]
                [...some other clause...]
                (or-join [?entitlement ?component]
                         (and [...some conditional stuff...])
                         (and [...some other conditional stuff...]))]
                db uid component)
```

...into something more readable. My desire is to locally bind the `(and...)` components of the query inside a `let` and refer to them by a name inside of the datalog list.  Like so:

```
(datomic.api/q '[:find [?value ...] :in $ ?uid ?component :where
                [...some clause...]
                [...some other clause...]
                (or-join [?entitlement ?component]
                         entitled-for-component
                         entitled-for-application)]
                db uid component)
```

Various quoting in `let` (and unquoting inside of datomic.api/q's list) have not worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yep. The quoting/unquoting approach sort-of works if you use syntax quoting, but then you'll end up with things like *and* being replaced by namespace-qualified symbols, which will break it a more different way. Your answer below is the way to go about it.

Comment: I like the answer below, to use rules. To quasiquote in Clojure like you would in other lisps, try the `template` form in [backtick](https://github.com/brandonbloom/backtick).

Answer (score 2):

Datomic uses [rules](http://docs.datomic.com/query.html) to solve this problem.

> Datomic datalog allows you to package up sets of :where clauses into
>   named rules. These rules make query logic reusable, and also
>   composable, meaning that you can bind portions of a query's logic at
>   query time.

Rulesets are defined as a list of lists, then used as an additional input with datomic.api/q bound to the % character.

```
(def rules [[(name-for-id restaurant-id?)
             [restaurant-id? :restaurant/name name?]]])

(datomic.api/q '[:find ?name . :in $ % ?restaurant-id :where
                 (name-for-id restaurant-id?)] db rules 42)

=> "Milliways"
```

Note that `datomic.api/q` expects a rule **set**, passing a single rule will not work.

The first list in a rule defines the rule name as the first item, followed by one or more parameters. The subsequent vectors contain one or more :where clauses.

Also,

> As with other where clauses, you may specify a database before the
>   rule-name to scope the rule to that database. Databases cannot be used
>   as arguments in a rule.

Comment: You missed a quote:
<code>
    (def rules '[[(name-for-id restaurant-id?)
                  [restaurant-id? :restaurant/name name?]]])
</code>